# Как можно реализовать двойное изменение объекта по клику мыши?

Tags: html, css

Пример: Мне нужно открывать модальное окно нажатием на ссылку, а затем закрывать его нажатием на ту же самую ссылку. Можно ли это реализовать, используя :target и не используя javaspript?

Comment: на фокусе можно - но тогда надо будет производить click вне :focus

Answer (score 3):

Вместо нажатия на ссылку для закрытия окна, я реализовал немного улучшенный метод - нажатие на иконку рядом с окном:

```css
  

a{
text-decoration: none; 
}
            
.Window {
overflow: auto;
z-index: 999;
transition: opacity 600ms ease-in;
display: none;
pointer-events: none;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
        
.close {
top: -15px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 14px;    
background: blue;
color: white;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -13px;
text-align: center;
}
    
.close:hover { 
background: red; 
}
    
.Window:target {
display: block;
pointer-events: auto;
}
        
.Window > div {
margin: 9% auto;
background: white;
width: 420px;
position: relative;
padding: 6px 19px 12px 19px;
border-radius: 14px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openWindow">Кликай =)</a>

<div id="openWindow" class="Window">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">X</a>
<h2>Простенькое модальное окно по заказу Apri =)</h2>
</br>
Жила была рыба и было у рыбы 7 ♂dungeon masters♂.
Говорила рыба своим ♂dungeon masters♂ в лес не ходить,
ведь там бродит злой и голодный ♂boss of this gym♂.
Однажды рыба ушла на пруд добывать ♂cum♂ своим ♂dungeon masters♂.
♂boss of this gym♂ узнал об этом с ноги сломал дверь и всем ♂dungeon masters♂ сделал ♂rip the Skin♂ 
Конец =)
</div>
</div>
```

---

UPD: Немного изменил дизайн иконки.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: _В остальном же все по заказу_. извините, но этот сайт не бюро заказов ;) В описани уделите бльше внимания технической стороне вашего решения.

Comment: Ну так это шутка =)

Comment: Благодарю за замечание, это мой первый ответ и я еще неопытен в таких делах

Comment: 0xdb, а вам сколько лет, если не секрет)? Реально ли стать программистом, когда тебе за 30 лет?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький Реально. Пожалуйста, не используйте комментарии для всего того, что не относится к вопросу или ответу в этом топике. Этот сайт не являеется форумом. Побочные темы вы можете обсудить в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но еще интересно, возможно ли реализовать и открытие, и закрытие окна через нажатие на одну и ту же кнопку. С закрытием через другую иконку все понятно, но вот как можно сделать так, чтобы на первый клик по ссылке открывалось окно, а потом по нажатию на эту же ссылку второй раз оно закрывалось

Comment: Не знаю, нужно поэкспериментировать, а это займет 2-4 часа реального времени. Задайте еще один вопрос и я постараюсь ответить вам =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите мой ответ нажмите на галочку слева от ответа =) Галочка очень сильно поможет мне =)